# How to make changes to a Javascript object from Node.js/Socket.io listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Sorry if the title is too vague, I'm not really sure what the problem is here.

I am attempting to make a basic program which allows users to start and join rooms. When the start button is pressed, a room is started with a random string code which other users can then use to join. I store the member counter for each room in a object 'rooms' using the room code as a key and the count as a value. However, when trying to increment the value, it returns the value as NaN.

I have attached my code below, it uses express 4.10.2 and socket.io 1.3.5:

javascript in index.html, enclosed in the body tags

```
  var socket = io.connect();

  //possible characters in room code
  var chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

  //for generating random room codes
  function randomString(c,length){
    var str = ''
    for(var i=0; i<length;i++){
      str += c[Math.round(Math.random()*(c.length-1))]
    }
    return str;
  }

  $('#join').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('joinroom', $('#code').val());
  });

  $('#start').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('startroom', randomString(chars,5));
  });

  //listener for 'updatecounter', updates room member count
  socket.on('updatecounter', function(count){
    $('#roomcount').append('<p>'+count.toString()+'</p>');
  });

  //listener for 'updateroom' - should update room code at top
  socket.on('updateroom', function(code){
    $('#roomcode').append('<h1>'+count.toString()+'</h1>');
  });
```

The section of my app.js in question:

```
//available rooms
var rooms = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    // when the client emits 'joinroom', this listens and executes
    socket.on('startroom', function(room){
        console.log('Starting room: '+room);
        //add to serverside list of rooms
        rooms[room]=1;
        socket.room = room;
        socket.join(room);
    });

    // when the client emits 'joinroom', this listens and executes
    socket.on('joinroom', function(room){
        console.log('Joining room '+room);
        //leave previous room
        socket.leave(socket.room);
        //join new room
        socket.join(room);
        //update socket session room title
        socket.room = room;
        //increase serverside counter
        rooms[room]++;
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        //decrement counter
        rooms[socket.room]--;
        //check if room is now empty
        if(rooms[socket.room]===0){
            delete rooms[socket.room]
        } 
        //leave the room
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm a beginner to JS as well as Node.js and Socket.IO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was caused by a form submission in my HTML code causing a page refresh which caused a disconnect/reconnect from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake may be relevant with 'updateroom' listener on client. Your parameter name is 'code' but you append count. This is wher you get NaN value?

Comment: I corrected the error there but adding console.log(rooms[room]) after the rooms[room]++; line still return NaN.

Comment: I would say only a disconnect may cause this and I see you figured it out.